# Memory Leaks in Silverlight 5

Tags: memory, silverlight-5.0

Anybody knows if Silverlight memory leaks are fixed in Silverlight 5?

I can´t find it in microsoft connect or some other place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: memory leaks in datagridcontrols with datatemplates.